# Which word is "they" referring to?

Tags: ambiguity, antecedents

Which word is **they** referring to in the following sentence?

> Children make circles because **they** are perfect.

Is it referring to **Children** or **circles**? And why?

Comment: The sentence is ambiguous: without context we can't be sure from the grammar which meaning is intended. I think "perfect" more likely applies to the circles, solely on the basis of which makes more sense.

Comment: children can't be perfect by definition ;) but circles mathematically are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, "they" could refer to either "children" or "circles", but as the comments suggest, "circles" makes much more sense. The only way to be sure, however, is through additional context. Consider a sentence with the same form, but different content:

> Angels make prophecies because they are perfect.

Now "they" seems more likely to refer to "Angels".

In the general case:

> Xs make Ys because they are perfect.

there is no way to tell the referent of "they" without additional context.